# Display Twitter timelines and lists on a website

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, plugin, twitter

I've built a Twitter plugin recently and was wondering if I could get some feedback on it.  There is also a PHP side that grabs the actual tweets and I can post that code if it's needed.

http://jsfiddle.net/cKfDd/

```
;(function ( $, window, document, undefined ) {
/*************************************
Plugin Functions    
*************************************/ 


/*************************************/
Plugin.prototype.init = function () {

    var params = [  '?user='     + this.options.user,
                    '&limit='    + this.options.limit,
                    '&type='     + this.options.type,
                    '&slug='     + this.options.slug,
                    '&cache='    + this.options.cache,
                    '&expire='   + this.options.expire,
                    '&clear='    + this.options.clear,
                    '&retweets=' + this.options.retweets
    ].join('\n');

    $.ajax({
        url: this.options.path_to_core + 'invisibletweets.php' + params,
        context: this,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){

            // If the errors object is returned, show the error and exit the script
            if(data.errors){
                $(this.element).html("Fatal Error: " + data.errors[0].message);
                return false;
            }

            // Variables
            var scope    = this;
            var parent   = this.element;
            var tpl      = "";
            var tplArray = scope.options.template.replace(/[\s,]+/g, ',').split(',');

            // Creates an empty template with all present data, in order.
            $.each(tplArray, function(i, elm){
                if(elm == 'name'){
                    tpl = tpl + '<div class="it_name"><a href="" target="_blank"></a></div>';
                } else if(elm == 'avatar'){
                    tpl = tpl + '<div class="it_avatar"><a href="" target="_blank"><img src="" /></a></div>';
                } else if(elm == 'date'){
                    tpl = tpl + '<div class="it_date"></div>';
                } else if(elm == 'time'){
                    tpl = tpl + '<div class="it_time"></div>';
                } else if(elm == 'text'){
                    tpl = tpl + '<div class="it_text"><p></p></div>';
                } else if(elm == 'btn_tweet'){
                    tpl = tpl + '<a href="http://twitter.com/intent/tweet?in_reply_to=" target="_blank" class="it_btn_tweet">Tweet</a>';
                } else if(elm == 'btn_retweet'){
                    tpl = tpl + '<a href="http://twitter.com/intent/retweet?tweet_id=" target="_blank" class="it_btn_retweet">Retweet</a>';
                } else if(elm == 'btn_favorite'){
                    tpl = tpl + '<a href="http://twitter.com/intent/favorite?tweet_id=" target="_blank" class="it_btn_favorite">Favorite</a>';
                }                   
            });

            //Populates the template with data
            $.each(data, function(i, item){

                // Variables
                var text        = scope.findLinks(item.text);
                var date        = scope.dateTime(item.created_at, 'date');
                var time        = scope.dateTime(item.created_at, 'time');
                var profile_url = 'http://twitter.com/' + item.user.screen_name;
                var thisTweet   = ".it_tweet:eq("+i+") ";

                // Creates a searchable object of the template
                $(parent).append('<div class="it_tweet">' + tpl + '</div>');

                //If in array, show, else don't show, for each item.
                if(tplArray.indexOf('name') != -1){
                    $(thisTweet + ".it_name a").attr("href", profile_url).html(item.user.name);
                }
                if(tplArray.indexOf('avatar') != -1){
                    $(thisTweet + ".it_avatar").find('a').attr("href", profile_url).find('img').attr("src", item.user.profile_image_url);
                }
                if(tplArray.indexOf('date') != -1){
                    $(thisTweet + ".it_date").html(date);
                }
                if(tplArray.indexOf('time') != -1){
                    $(thisTweet + ".it_time").html(time);
                }
                if(tplArray.indexOf('text') != -1){
                    $(thisTweet + ".it_text p").html(text);
                }
                if(tplArray.indexOf('btn_tweet') != -1){
                    $(thisTweet + ".it_btn_tweet").attr("href", 'http://twitter.com/intent/tweet?in_reply_to=' + item.id);
                }
                if(tplArray.indexOf('btn_retweet') != -1){
                    $(thisTweet + ".it_btn_retweet").attr("href", 'http://twitter.com/intent/retweet?tweet_id=' + item.id);
                }
                if(tplArray.indexOf('btn_favorite') != -1){
                    $(thisTweet + ".it_btn_favorite").attr("href", 'http://twitter.com/intent/favorite?tweet_id=' + item.id);
                }

            }); //each

        } //success
    }); //ajax

}; //init


/*************************************/
Plugin.prototype.findLinks = function(tweet){
    var text = tweet;

    text = text.replace(/http:\/\/\S+/g,  '<a href="$&" target="_blank">$&</a>');
    text = text.replace(/\s(@)(\w+)/g,    ' @<a href="http://twitter.com/$2" target="_blank">$2</a>');
    text = text.replace(/\s(#)(\w+)/g,    ' #<a href="http://twitter.com/search?q=%23$2" target="_blank">$2</a>');

    return text;
}; //findLinks


/*************************************/
Plugin.prototype.dateTime = function(created_at, select){
    var dateTime = created_at;
    var strtime = dateTime.replace(/(\+\S+) (.*)/, '$2 $1')
    var date = new Date(Date.parse(strtime)).toLocaleDateString();
    var time = new Date(Date.parse(strtime)).toLocaleTimeString();

    if(select == 'date'){
        return date;
    } else if(select == 'time'){
        return time;
    }
}; //dateTime


/*************************************
Plugin Setup    
*************************************/ 

var pluginName = 'invisibleTweets',

// Options for the plugin
defaults = {
    user        : 'shanrobertson_',                                                         // Twitter username
    limit       : 10,                                                                       // Number of tweets
    type        : 'timeline',                                                               // Feed select, can be timeline/list
    slug        : '',                                                                       // For lists
    cache       : 'default',                                                                // The cache name if dealing with multiple feeds
    expire      : '15 minutes',                                                             // The time it takes the cache to expire
    clear       : false,                                                                    // Clears the cache.
    retweets    : true,                                                                     // Show retweets
    path_to_core: 'js/vendor/invisibletweets/',                                             // Path to the invisibletweets folder.
    template    : 'name, avatar, date, time, text, btn_tweet, btn_retweet, btn_favorite'    // Elements to show and in what order
};

// The actual plugin constructor
function Plugin( element, options ) {
    this.element = element;
    this.options = $.extend( {}, defaults, options);
    this._defaults = defaults;
    this._name = pluginName;

    this.init();
}

// A really lightweight plugin wrapper around the constructor, preventing against multiple instantiations
$.fn[pluginName] = function ( options ) {
    return this.each(function () {
        if (!$.data(this, 'plugin_' + pluginName)) {
            $.data(this, 'plugin_' + pluginName, 
            new Plugin( this, options ));
        }
    });
}

})( jQuery, window, document );
```

Answer (score 2):

The code over all looks nice and clean and is very readable.

What I'm not really a fan of is the handling of the template.

- Personally I'd prefer to define the template directly as an array instead of a comma separated string.
- The big if block building the HTML should be replaced with an object (hash map) with the HTML snippets assigned to each keyword.
- String concatenations are slow and memory hogs. It would be better to collect the string in an array and `.join('')` them.
- It's a bit strange to add the template to the page first and then search for it again before filling it. It would be much easier to first fill the template and then add it to the page.
- Generally I'd join building and filling the template into one:

Here some (untested) code showing what I mean:

```
var tplArray = ['name', 'avatar'];

var templateItems = {
    name: {
        template: '<div class="it_name"><a href="" target="_blank"></a></div>',
        fill: function(element, itemData) {
            element.find("a").attr("href", itemData.profile_url).html(itemData.user.name);
        }
    },
    avatar: {
        template: '<div class="it_avatar"><a href="" target="_blank"><img src="" /></a></div>',
        fill: function(element, itemData) {
            element.find('a').attr("href", itemData.profile_url).find('img').attr("src", itemData.user.profile_image_url);
        }
    }
    // etc.
}

$.each(data, function(i, item){
    // Put formated data into back into item
    item.text        = scope.findLinks(item.text);
    item.date        = scope.dateTime(item.created_at, 'date');
    item.time        = scope.dateTime(item.created_at, 'time');
    item.profile_url = 'http://twitter.com/' + item.user.screen_name;
    item.thisTweet   = ".it_tweet:eq("+i+") ";

    var templateItems = $.map(tplArray, function(i, tplItem) {
        var templateData = templateItems[tplItem];
        var element = $(templateData.template);
        templateData.fill(element, item);
        return element;
    });

    $(parent).append($('<div class="it_tweet"></div>').append(templateItems));
});
```